# tcpdump: capture one of several vlans

Tags: sniffing, vlan, packet-capture, tcpdump

I want tcpdump to capture VLAN 1000 or VLAN 501. `man pcap-filter` says:

> The  vlan [vlan_id] expression may be used more than once, to filter on VLAN hierarchies.  Each use of that expression increments the filter offsets by 4.

When I do:

```
tcpdump -vv -i eth1 \( vlan 1000 \) and \( ip host 10.1.1.98 or ip host 10.1.1.99 \)
```

I get captured packets.

But when I do:

```
tcpdump -vv -i eth1 \( vlan 1000 or vlan 501 \) and \( ip host 10.1.1.98 or ip host 10.1.1.99 \)
```

I don't get any packets -- I presume because of the "increment by 4" behavior described in the man page.

How can I capture traffic on more than one VLAN at a time?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I remembered that you can examine the packet bytes directly. So looking directly into the ethernet header works:

```
tcpdump -vv -i eth1 '( vlan and ( ether[14:2] & 0xfff == 1000 or ether[14:2] & 0xfff == 501 ) ) and ( ip host 10.1.1.98 or ip host 10.1.1.99 )'
```

Don't forget the `:2`, this is a 2 byte field -- I got stuck on this for a while.

Answer (score 9):

It can be done in more simply way than using deep packet exam, just use grep:

```
tcpdump -n -i eth1 -e | grep "vlan 1000"
```

**-e:** Print the link-level header on each dump line.

it will print lines like

```
ethertype 802.1Q (0x8100), length 60: vlan 1000, p 0, ethertype ARP
```

which can be easily catch by grep

If you want catch more than one VLAN ID you can use command like:

```
tcpdump -n -i eth1 -e | grep "vlan 1000\|vlan 501"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the vlan filter shifts the packet contents....

http://www.christian-rossow.de/articles/tcpdump_filter_mixed_tagged_and_untagged_VLAN_traffic.php

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers.  They are low-quality, because links can change/go stale.  It's best to include the necessary details directly in your post, and provide the link only for reference.